# Parse pagination in html. using jsoup

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I'm trying to parse website for getting some information about goods in store.
But i have some questions about: how to parse pagination.
I found on html some information about few urls like: "1,2,3..,25" pages of goods. But best what i can imagine how to parse this urls, just get url, get last page and do iteration for this page: for example url which i got by using method Jsoup.connect(website.com).get().getElementsByClass("someclass");
`https://somewebsite.com/somegoods/somecategory/page=1/, https://somewebsite.com/somegoods/somecategory/page=2/,
https://somewebsite.com/somegoods/somecategory/page=24/`
but sometimes urls like:
`https://somewebsite.com/somegoods/somecategory/filter/page=1;some_information_later/
https://somewebsite.com/somegoods/somecategory/filter/page=2;some_information_later/
https://somewebsite.com/somegoods/somecategory/filter/page=13;some_information_later/`

May you please help me with it? I have tried to use regex, but I don't know how to write it for getting numbers after "page=" and before / or ;
I thought I can just get last number of page, and make iteration from 1 to last, and put it in URL and save it to hashset of URLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture groups can be used to get specific substrings from a string that matches your regex.  Parenthesis mark capture groups.  So, the regex for the page number itself would be `"page=(\\d+)"`.  To get thr value of the group from a match, use the `group` method from your Matcher object.  If you're not already using an Matcher obeject, you can create one from your Pattern.  Also, you should note that your first group is index 1 (index 0 gives the whole matching string).

For more information:
Group method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)
Matcher: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Thank you alot my code is working now, but not really readable, but it works!